# Invariance of the (Liouville-Roth) irrationality measure under rational Möbius transformations

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-approximation

For a real number $x$, we define the (Liouville-Roth) irrationality measure of $x$, here denoted by $\mu(x)$, as the infimum, with respect to the poset $(\mathbb{R}_0^+ \cup \{\infty\}, \le)$, of the (possibly empty) set of all real exponents $s > 0$ such that the inequality
$$0 < \left|x - \frac{m}{n}\right| < \frac{1}{n^s} $$
holds true for finitely many pairs $(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{N}^+$ (with the convention that $\sup(\emptyset) := \infty$).

Now, fix $\tilde{x} \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $M: \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\} \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ be the Möbius transformation
$$
x \mapsto \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
(ax+b)/(cx+d) & \text{if }x \ne \infty \\
a/c           & \text{if }c \ne 0 \text{ and }x = \infty \\
\infty        & \text{if }(c = 0 \text{ and }x = \infty) \text{ or }(c \ne 0 \text{ and }x = - d/c)\\
\end{array}\right.,
$$
where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Q$ and $ad-bc \ne 0$. It is then possible to prove that $\mu(\tilde{x}) = \mu(M(\tilde{x}))$ provided that $c\tilde{x}+d \ne 0$, and here come my questions:

> > **Q1.** Is there a "standard" reference for this? I checked Mahler's *Lectures on Diophantine Approximations* and Schmidt's *Diophantine Approximations and Diophantine Equations*, but the result doesn't seem to be mentioned in either of them. **Q2.** From the historical point of view, who was the first one who proved the result? Maybe J. Liouville, in his early work in diophantine approximation theory?

Thank you beforehand for any help.

Comment: See section 2.8 in *Heights in diophantine geometry* by Bombieri and Gubler, particularly Prop. 2.8.19.

Comment: Better: see the original source, K. K. Choi and J. D. Vaaler, *Diophantine approximation in projective space*: http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/~choi/paper/metric.pdf .

Comment: Thank you, Vesselin, all the more that Choi and Vaaler's paper points to Cassels' _An introduction to diophantine approximation_ (Ch. I, Sect. 3, p. 11) for the basic case of ${\rm PGL}(2,\mathbb{Q})$ and approximations to reals by rational numbers.

Comment: I looked closer to Choi and Vaaler's results and Cassels' corollary on p. 11 of his book, and this morning, on a second thought, I don't see the relation with my questions. Those results do not apply to the Liouville-Roth irrationality exponent, but to the alternative measure of irrationality that we get by replacing $n^s$ with $s^{-1}n^2$ in the OP (which is relevant, in particular, in the study of badly approximable numbers). What do I miss?

Comment: Take $N=M=2$ and $\mathbb{x} :=(1:x)$, $\mathbb{y} := (1:m/n)$ in Thm. 3, with the projective distance defined in (1.2). Your question follows since $|\mathbb{x} \wedge \mathbb{y}| = |x-m/n|$. So you may quote the paper of Choi and Vaaler as a reference to a much more general setting.

Comment: Thanks, Vesselin, for your explanations. Finally, I seem to get the point, but let me try to write down some further details: It suffices to prove that $\mu(M(x))\le\mu:=\mu(x)$. If $\mu=\infty$ or $x$ is rational, this is trivial, so assume $\mu < \infty$ and $x\notin\mathbb{Q}$, and pick $\varepsilon > 0$. We'd like to prove that $|M(x)-p/q|\ge q^{-\mu+\varepsilon}$ for all but finitely many _reduced_ pairs $(p,q)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}^+$ with $|qM(x)-p|<1$. For, pick $\varepsilon>0$ and a reduced pair $(p,q)$ with $q$ large enough. Then, putting $m := -bq+dp$ and (...)

Comment: (...) $n:=aq-cp$ yields $M(m/n)=p/q$, to the effect that, by specializing the Choi-Vaaler inequality to the case mentioned in Vesselin's last comment, we have:
$$\left|M(x)-\frac{p}{q}\right|=|M(x)-M(m/n)|\ge \eta_\infty(A)^{-1}\cdot\left|x-\frac{m}{n}\right|\ge\frac{\eta_\infty(A)^{-1}}{|n|^{\mu-2\varepsilon}}\ge\frac{\kappa}{q^{\mu-2\varepsilon}}\ge\frac{1}{q^{\mu - \varepsilon}},$$
where $\kappa := \eta_\infty(A)^{-1} \cdot ((|a|+|c|) \cdot (M(x)+1))^{2\varepsilon - \mu}$ and $A$ is the matrix of $M$. The conclusion follows from the arbitrariness of $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Yet, even though all of this is cute, I'd prefer a more "classical" reference to the basic result for the case "$\mathbb{Q}$ vs $\mathbb{R}$".